# Can't take the result from JSON data. I take the undefined result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to reach out SpeechRegions' datas in Channel. When i write "console.log(speech.Channels)", i can see this json data below. But when i write "console.log(speech.Channels.SpeechRegions)", it gives me undefined. Can you explain to me its reason?

```
Channels: [
    {
      SilenceRegions: [],
      SpeechRegions: [Array],
      SilenceDuration: 0,
      SpeechDuration: 8.68,
      SilenceRatio: 0,
      SpeechRatio: 1,
      InterruptCount: 0,
      Channel: 0
    }
  ],
```

Comment: `Channels` is an array, so you have to specify which element to take. `speech.Channels[0].SpeechRegions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json is nested in array
Channels: []

So You need to refer to first element in array :
Channels[0]

Then refer to :
Channels[0].SpeechRegions

Answer (score 0):

As `speech.Channels` is an array (notice by `[]` after `Channels:` , you have to use an index like so:

```
speech.Channels[0].SpeechRegions
```

Also, only use arrays if there could be more than one json objects as result.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the index of Channel object in Channels array to get the prop value of object

speech.Channels[index].SpeechRegions